# How to auto-collapse all backlog items by default in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

Using Team Foundation Server 2103(Web Access).

Whenever I navigate to Backlogs -> My current iteration, I see the User Stories as well as the Tasks all auto expanded.

What I want is I want to default it to Collapse.

Is there any setting for that?

[image]

Comment: Why do you have so many PBI's in your iteration that this is an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an iteration view want you care about is the Tasks (the plan) rather than just the PBI's and this is the default behavior. There is currently no way to change it.

Comment: Partially makes sense but they do give option to collapse so they know there's some use. Why we have so many PBI's is due to 10 member team and we just started with TFS, our first iteration. We have some previous in-progress items added, constantly coming in production issues, etc.

Comment: I would suggest that for future iteration you will likely have less and the need with reduce. You can suggest this as a new feature on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com